# Is there any ideas on webform mutile values on same field?

Tags: webforms

In webform select components, we can set multiple attributes but not for filed like textfield or numbers.

So I want to ask is there any ideas on that, so let user can add more value  on same field. Such as:

Telephone number, the web visitors may not have only one ,and we should allows multiple for that.

We found that the webform has store multiple  values in database which can come from in the form used like telephone[], but do not in the validation.

We do not want to changes the validation rules but we want to have a multiple attributes on textfied.

Is there any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is module for doing this: Try the [Multivalue Settings](http://drupal.org/project/multivalue_settings) module.

> This module adds some useful settings for fields that can contain multiple values. You can specify:
>
> - Number of values allowed
> - Number of values required
> - Number of empty widgets to display initially (Drupal usually displays all fields for non-unlimited fields. This allows you to only display a few, followed by the 'Add More' button, which will disappear after the maximum number of fields has been filled.)
> - Number of empty widgets to display on edit forms after the field contains some values (Drupal usually displays one extra.)

Comment: Much Thanks, it seems not for the webform textfiled field.

Comment: Sorry to lead to the misunderstood. Actually,  the Multivalue Settings module is useful in a normal drupal form. While webform is another drupal module which allows we create a form in node not as a content type. And my question is on webform's filed, I'd like to see if any predecessors have done that or give some ideas for that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try [Webform Multiple](https://drupal.org/project/wfm).

> Webform Multiple (WFM) is a Drupal 7 module allowing Webform
>   components to have more than one value.
>
> The user completing the form can add instances of the component with
>   an 'Add another item' button.

Hope it can help you